# Is it possible to configure ELMAH entirely in code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I'd like to configure ELMAH for an ASP.NET MVC site entirely in code. This includes registering the module, setting the logging provider and settings, and filtering exceptions.

The only part I've managed to do so far is filter exceptions. Has anyone else figured out how to do this? I'd really like to avoid cluttering up my config file with settings that won't ever change.

Comment: Brian - Isn't that the point of a config file, to store things that don't change ever or often?  Things that do change frequently, you would want in your code base.  Just a thought...

Comment: I'm rolling out multiple instances of an ASP.NET MVC system to many clients. As such, I'd like to keep the config files as simple as possible.

Comment: @Tommy: I think you meant the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that using version 1.2 beta http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/list?&q=label%3AMilestone-Release1.2+status=Fixed&can=1

Answer (score 2):

[Link to the original bug/feature in google code.](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=149&can=1&q=label%3AMilestone-Release1.2%20status%3DFixed&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified)

[Link to a google groups discussion giving basic sample code for implementing the service container.](http://groups.google.com/group/elmah/browse_thread/thread/accb494284d08b87?pli=1)

```
static ServiceProviderQueryHandler 
CreateServiceProviderQueryHandler(IServiceProvider sp) { 
  return context => { 
    var container = new ServiceContainer(sp); 
    var log = new SqlErrorLog("…connection string…"); 
    container.AddService(typeof(ErrorLog), log); 
    return container; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ELMAH runs as a custom HTTP module and HTTP handler. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx):

> After you have created a custom HTTP
>   handler class, you must register it in
>   the Web.config file. This enables
>   ASP.NET to call the HTTP handler in
>   order to service requests for
>   resources that have the specified file
>   name extension.
>
> How you register an HTTP handler
>   depends on the version of Internet
>   Information Services (IIS) that hosts
>   your application. For IIS 6.0, you
>   register the handler by using the
>   httpHandlers section of the Web.config
>   file. For IIS 7.0 running in Classic
>   mode, you register the handler in the
>   httpHandlers section, and you map the
>   handler to the Aspnet_isapi.dll file.
>   For IIS 7.0 running in Integrated
>   mode, you register the handler by
>   using the handlers element in the
>   system.WebServer section.

[Rick Strahl has a blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/44979.aspx) where he programmatically registers an HttpModule. I suppose it might be possible to use a similar technique with ELMAH.